# What does a Bryant sphere in dimension 2 look like?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Recently I saw a definition of a Bryant sphere, which is a sphere equipped with a non-Riemannian Finsler metric on $S^n$ that satisfies the following properties:

- $ K=1 $,
- All geodesics are great circles,
- All prime geodesics have the same length $ 2π $.

The antipodal  map $\Phi$ for a Bryant sphere is $\Phi(x) = −x$, $\forall x ∈S^n ⊂\mathbb{R}^n+1$.

I felt that perhaps a Bryant sphere in the case $n=2$ is the same as the standard sphere $S^2$ which imbeds in $\mathbb{R}^3$, specifically because they have the same antipodal map.
But these two spheres are completely different in the case $n=2$.
I don't know much about Finsler metrics, but do you think the metric makes a big difference or, perhaps it is better to ask what causes this difference?

Comment: What is a "non-Riemannian metric"? a distance? a Finsler metric?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I forgot to write it was a non-Riemannian Finsler metric

Comment: My intuition for Finsler geometry is that you try to draw the unit sphere in each tangent space, which in this case you can compare to the usual unit sphere. But that doesn't seem to give much intuition, in particular as to how the Gauss-Finsler curvature manages to be constant. In my mental picture of a surface, it is always embedded in Euclidean 3-space, which makes me a bad topologist. If it has a metric, I imagine it isometrically embedded, which makes me a bad differential geometer.

Comment: @Ben McKay, Thank you for sharing your intuition. Do you mean unit balls? I only know little Finsler, but apparently, on Finsler manifolds, the additional structure, F(x,-), Minkowski function helps to define a kind of the norm in each tangent spaces which the norm induces a metric. ( While we have the inner product and so induced metric ) I guess in the end they will have a normed metric vector space in each tangent space. So they have unit balls in each tangent space and some possibilities like having the continuous linear operators. Please correct my word and guess.

Comment: Can the Finsler metric / distance function be approximated by Riemannian one?

Comment: Yes, you have a norm in each tangent space, so you can draw its unit sphere, and conversely if in each tangent space, you have a convex body invariant under taking a vector to its negative, and it varies in some sense smoothly, you get a Finsler metric. So you can try to draw such a thing. This is useful perhaps in imagining translation invariant Finsler metrics on the plane, but I don't see how it helps to understand Bryant spheres,

Comment: I am pretty sure that Finsler metrics cannot be approximated in any useful way by Riemannian ones. You could try to get a Riemannian upper or lower bound, but I doubt you will see anything about Gauss-Finsler curvature.

Comment: @VítTuček, May you please tell me your " constructive definition " of approximation a metric by the other one?, specifically for Finslerian and Riemannian types. ( I've 
 just seen a kind of approximation in metric geometry, like approximating arbitrary metrics by tree metric.)